# rails-pundit does enum role: require a migration to create a new column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, enums

This is from an answer posted by Danile Kehoe:

"Roles are defined in the app/models/User.rb file (the User model).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
 .
  .
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

end
```

The application uses the ActiveRecord enum method to manage roles. ActiveRecord provides convenient methods to query the role attribute:

```
user.admin! # sets the role to "admin"
user.admin? # => true
user.role  # => "admin"
```

See documentation for ActiveRecord::Enum for details. The ActiveRecord enum method is new in Rails 4.1."

**My** question is, wouldn't this require running a migration to add a ":role" column to the User table?  I don't know how/where else pundit would store the hash unless Pundit has some automagical way of doing it. My User table (different example than this one) was created using devise, and has no :role column. Yet. My instinct is to add one, but I don't want to break the app by conflicting with something under Pundit's hood.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. If you intent to use it this way you have to run migration and add role to User model with integer type:

```
rails g migration AddRoleToUser role:integer
```

Method `set_default_role` sets default role for newly created user with role :user.